# How to convert JSON messages to DataFrame in Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

i have a spark stream code that read from kafka, but the value that i have is like this:

```
"{ id:'1',name: 'John', address: 'Highway 37' }|{ id:'2',name: 'Marta', address: 'Highway 37' }|{ id:'3',name: 'Juan', address: 'Highway 37' }|{ id:'4',name: 'Erick', address: 'Highway 37' }|{ id:'6',name: 'Alex', address: 'Highway 37' }|{ id:'7',name: 'Juanjo', address: 'Highway 37' }|{ id:'8',name: 'Pam', address: 'Highway 37' }|{ id:'9',name: 'Paty', address: 'Highway 37' }|{ id:'10',name: 'Diana', address: 'Highway 37' }"
```

is a string set of json, this is my kafka value:

```
val kafkaRawData = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS string)")
```

but i want to convert this string json set of data to dataframe or dataset, and how could i do it???

Comment: or anyway of do it , if i have one by one and how could  i accumulate it an turn it to df all set ??

Comment: I don't think this is a valid jason. can you add more details like input message and output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply be using [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) standard function and [DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter) operator that has the following signature:

```
foreachBatch(function: (Dataset[T], Long) ⇒ Unit): DataStreamWriter[T]
```

With `from_json` you convert your strings into proper JSONs while `foreachBatch` gives you access to `Datasets` per micro-batch.

Answer (score 1):

Use `from_json` function to handle conversion of json strings to objects. To simplify this, or to make it more general, save a sample json string in a file to read from it to infer the schema. Use this schema and pass it to the function. Sometimes, in case of complex json objects, creating a schema using `StructType` can become cumbersome.

```
val schema = spark.read.json(sampleFilePath).schema
inputDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as data")
    .select(from_json(col("data"),schema).as("data"))
```